# Tengo un problemas con este código, ya que funciona bien en la versión PHP 7, pero en la versión PHP 8 no funciona, me sale error 500

Tags: php, soap, cpanel, php8

Me puede ayudar por favor, este es el código, que funciona bien en la **versión 7 de php, pero en la versión 8 de php me arroja error 500 del servidor**, alguna solucione para mejorar este código. si me ayudar por favor si tengo que cambiar alguna variable $result = obj2array($result);

```html
<?php

session_start();
$usuario = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$servicio="http://administrativo.ganaycobra.com/BOSSWebServices/IncomingIntegrationService/IncomingIntegrationService.svc?wsdl"; //url del servicio


$parametros=array(); //parametros de la llamada
$parametros['sourceId']="GANAYCOBRAID";
$parametros['sourcePassword']="g4n4yc0br4";
$parametros['playerId']=$usuario;
$parametros['password']=$password;
$parametros['userId']="INETUSR";
 
$parametros['workstationId']=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$parametros['applicationId']="SBBR";
$parametros['logonSource']="1";
$parametros['websiteId']="6404";
$parametros['partnerId']="House";
$parametros['thridPartyToken']=""; 


$client = new SoapClient($servicio);
$result = $client->PlayerLogin($parametros);    //llamamos al métdo que nos interesa con los parámetros
$result = obj2array($result);



function obj2array($obj) {
  $out = array();
  foreach ($obj as $key => $val) {
    switch(true) {
        case is_object($val):
         $out[$key] = obj2array($val);
         break;
      case is_array($val):
         $out[$key] = obj2array($val);
         break;
      default:
        $out[$key] = $val;
    }
  }
  return $out;
}

//print_r($result);
if(!isset($_SESSION['stoken'])){
    $_SESSION['stoken']='';
}
$_SESSION['stoken']='';
$stoken = $result[PlayerLoginResult]['Token']; 
setcookie("stoken", $stoken, time()+(60*20));
$_SESSION['stoken']=$stoken;

//  Obtenemos el fondo del usuario
if ($stoken!=""){
    $parametros_2=array(); //parametros de la llamada
    $parametros_2['sourceId']="GANAYCOBRAID";
    $parametros_2['sourcePassword']="g4n4yc0br4";
    //$parametros_2['playerId']=$usuario;
    $parametros_2['token']=$stoken;

    $client_2 = new SoapClient($servicio, $parametros_2);
    //$result_2 = $client_2->GetFunds($parametros_2);    //llamamos al métdo que nos interesa con los parámetros
    $result_2 = $client_2->GetPlayerPersonalInformation($parametros_2);    //llamamos al métdo que nos interesa con los parámetros
    $result_2 = obj2array($result_2);

    $_SESSION['balance']='';
    $_SESSION['CustomerId']='';
    $_SESSION['Email']='';
    $_SESSION['CurrencyLocalizedSymbol']='';
    $_SESSION['TotalCurrentWeekWonLost']='';
    $_SESSION['CurrentWeekInOut']='';

    $balance = $result_2[GetPlayerPersonalInformationResult]['PlayerInfo']['CurrentBalance'];
    $CustomerId = $result_2[GetPlayerPersonalInformationResult]['PlayerInfo']['CustomerId'];
    $Email = $result_2[GetPlayerPersonalInformationResult]['PlayerInfo']['Email'];
    $CurrencyLocalizedSymbol = $result_2[GetPlayerPersonalInformationResult]['PlayerInfo']['CurrencyLocalizedSymbol'];
    $TotalCurrentWeekWonLost = $result_2[GetPlayerPersonalInformationResult]['PlayerInfo']['TotalCurrentWeekWonLost'];
    $CurrentWeekInOut = $result_2[GetPlayerPersonalInformationResult]['PlayerInfo']['CurrentWeekInOut'];

    
    $_SESSION['balance']=$balance ;
    $_SESSION['CustomerId']=$CustomerId;
    $_SESSION['Email']=$Email;
    $_SESSION['CurrencyLocalizedSymbol']=$CurrencyLocalizedSymbol;
    $_SESSION['TotalCurrentWeekWonLost']=$TotalCurrentWeekWonLost;
    $_SESSION['CurrentWeekInOut']=$CurrentWeekInOut;
    //print_r($result_2);exit();
}
//echo $_SESSION['stoken']; exit();
if ($stoken!="")
    echo '<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">top.window.location.href = "./hipismo/";</script>'; 
else
    echo '<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">parent.window.location.href = "javascript:history.back(1)";alert("Usuario o Contraseña invalidos!");</script>';

?>
```

Me puede ayudar por favor, este es el código, que funciona bien en la versión 7 de php, pero en la versión 8 de php me arroja error 500 del servidor, alguna solucione para mejorar este código. si me ayudar por favor si tengo que cambiar alguna variable $result = obj2array($result);

Comment: Hay entradas en el error log?

Answer (score 0):

```
$stoken = $result[PlayerLoginResult]['Token']; PlayerLoginResult es una constante indefinida, y lo mismo pasa con los `[GetPlayerPersonal...`
```

esos son los errores que me marca VSCode, tal vez eso vaya entre comillas, no entiendo bien de donde salen las constantes, pero lo que si es seguro es que tus errores están en las líneas 53, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82